# Is using mysql_num_rows a lot slows page loading?

Tags: php, mysql

I built a classified. In the main/index.php page, I have many categories like cars, electronics, furniture..etc which you click on and give you the list of available cars or cell phones you can buy in your town.

I am thinking to add/show the number of ads each category contains like:
cars(74) electronics(32) and so on..

using of course mysql_num_rows

My question is> is this going to make loading the index.php page slower? if yes how slow? milliseconds, seconds, a lot?

Thanks :)

UPDATE >> CODE:

```
$query="select * FROM db_post WHERE cat='cars'";
$result= mysql_query($query);
$carnum=mysql_num_rows($result));

 <td class="car"> <li class="listclass"> <a href="city.php?cat=cars">CARS <?php echo "("."$carnum".")"; ?></a></li> </td> <?php echo  ?>
```

All I want is the number. Is there a difference between mysql_num_rows and SELECT COUNT(*) in terms of speed?

Comment: you can share some code?

Comment: I am going to visit my friend's family. How long it wouild take to drive there - couple minutes, several hours, a week?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not matter of speed of "poage load".
It is matter of the very basics of database usage.
The main rule is:

**Always select only data you need.**

If you need only count of rows - select count of rows, not rows to count them after.
Got the idea?

Make database to do as much calculations as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Would be best to cache the values if possible.  On a low usage website you won't see much of a difference, but add a lot of users, you would want to cache the values until they are changed.

Comment: Nothing THAT best in the caching. As long as you can stay without a cache, you stay without a headache.

Answer (score 2):

Using `mysql_num_rows()` alone isn't inherently slow. If you're using it because (say) you're selecting every product and displaying the number of matched rows, though, **that** will be slow! If all you need is a count, make the database do the counting with a query like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... WHERE ...
```

If you need a bunch of counts, use something like:

```
SELECT ..., COUNT(*) FROM ... WHERE ... GROUP BY ...
```

In general, try to decrease the total number of rows returned by the SQL server for the whole page by avoiding unnecessary queries, returning unused rows, or loading data when a summary is sufficient. As a general rule, fewer returned rows is better!

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like
 `select category_name, count( category_id ) from table group by category_id`

Ideally you would want to cache these results and run query the every minute or so if you have alot of data (many thousands of rows on a basic server) and alot of traffic (many thousands of hits a day). If you are only having hundreds of hits a day, I wouldnt worry as your solution would probably be fine.